# Differences between AddHttpClient<TClient> and AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, httpclientfactory

**HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.AddHttpClient** has several overloads. Some of them has `AddHttpClient<TClient>` signature and other has `AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation>`.

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0):

`AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation>` - Adds the IHttpClientFactory and related services to the IServiceCollection and configures a binding between the TClient type and a named HttpClient.

`AddHttpClient<TClient>`  - Adds the IHttpClientFactory and related services to the IServiceCollection and configures a binding between the TClient type and a named HttpClient.

I dont' understand when I supposed to use the first overload and when I supposed to use the second overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the second one will register `TImplementation` as `TClient`, i.e. if you have an interface like `IMyTypedClient` you want to resolve then you will use the first one:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyTypedClient, MyTypedClientImpl>();
```

And then you will resolve `IMyTypedClient` in some service.

And if you want to resolve the implementation directly then you will use the first one - `builder.Services.AddHttpClient<MyTypedClientImpl>();` and then you will need to resolve `MyTypedClientImpl`.

Basically the relation is the same as between `Add{Lifetime}<TService>` and `Add{Lifetime}<TService,TImplementation>` methods.

Comment: So does it mean that AddHttpClient<IMyTypedClient, MyTypedClientImpl> does two things, the first thing is that it binds IMyTypedClient to MyTypedClientImpl and the second thing is that it resolve HttpClient?

Comment: @daniil_ both of them create a specific factory which will construct the dependency implementation and inject there `HttpClient`. The difference is only the "return type" so to speak.